# Strapi gives 404 error after deployment to Netlify

Tags: gatsby, netlify, strapi

I have made a small project using Gatsby and Strapi (open-source cms).
When I run the project local, I get all the content types from Strapi perfectly.
But when I wanna deploy the project to netlify, the deploy fails and I get a 404 error in the console.

```
info Starting to fetch data from Strapi - https://agitated-euclid-2d5577.netlify.com/blogposts
error "gatsby-source-strapi" threw an error while running the sourceNodes lifecycle:
Request failed with status code 404
```

In my `gatsby-config.js` I use the `gatsby-source-strapi`.

```
{
  resolve: `gatsby-source-strapi`,
  options: {
    apiURL: process.env.DEPLOY_URL
      ? "https://agitated-euclid-2d5577.netlify.com"
      : "http://localhost:1337",
    contentTypes: [`blogposts`],
    queryLimit: 1000,
  },
},
```

And in my Strapi dashboard, I have set `blogpost` permission to `find`. I don't think it is because of permission, the error appears.

Comment: `https://agitated-euclid-2d5577.netlify.com` is the URL to your HTTP host. Shouldn't you supply the URL to your strappi project API?

Comment: Not according this guide https://strapi.io/blog/building-a-static-website-using-gatsby-and-strapi/#11deploygatsbytonetlify

Answer (score 0):

Your deploy URL is not correct. It should be the URL of your Strapi app in production.

Here you set the URL of your frontend APP in production.

If you follow the tuto, we set the HEROKU URL of the app. It's the production URL of the Strapi app. Not the URL of your frontend application.